# Migrating models of dependencies when changing DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm using Django 3.2. I've changed added this line to `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I then ran these commands:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

The `makemigrations` command creates new migration files for my apps, not just the apps that I have created, but also in my dependencies. For example, I'm using `django-allauth`, and this file was created in my virtual environment (virtualenv):

```
 .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/account/migrations/0003_auto_20210408_1526.py
```

This file is not shipped with `django-allauth`. When I deploy this application from git, this file is not included.

What should I do instead? How can I switch `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` without the need to create new migration files for dependencies like `django-allauth`?

Comment: Don't update to Django 3.2 until your dependencies do that. Individual apps can set [AppConfig.default_auto_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.default_auto_field) to specify the default auto field to use for their app. I believe most of the popular packages would add this to their app configs to prevent such situations.

Comment: Note that new versions of allauth don't have this problem any more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ideally, your third party dependencies would include this line in the config found in `apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ExampleConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

While waiting for upstream dependencies to update their `apps.py` or migration files, you can override the app config yourself. If it doesn't exist already, create an `apps.py` file in your main app directory (eg: `project/apps.py`), and override the config of a dependency. In this example, I'm overriding the config of `django-allauth`:

```
from allauth.account.apps import AccountConfig
from allauth.socialaccount.apps import SocialAccountConfig

class ModifiedAccountConfig(AccountConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'

class ModifiedSocialAccountConfig(SocialAccountConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

Then modify `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` to look like this, replacing the old entries for `django-allauth` in this example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ....
    # replace: "allauth.account", with
    "projectname.apps.ModifiedAccountConfig",
    # replace: "allauth.socialaccount", with
    "projectname.apps.ModifiedSocialAccountConfig",
]
```

If the dependency doesn't have an `apps.py` file to override, you can still create an `AppConfig` sub-class in `project/apps.py` like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ModifiedExampleDependencyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'exampledependency' # the python module
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
```

Now when you run `python manage.py makemigrations`, no migration files should be created for the dependencies.

Comment: Note that new versions of allauth don't have this problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

I work on a big project, we upgraded Django from 2.2. to 3.2 and then have got a need to create all new models with Big Integer (Int8) (PostgreSQL) field instead of default Integer (Int4).

When I defined it in `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I got the same problem, but with own apps - Django tried to make me to migrate 135 models I had, but I didn't want to do it. I only wanted to create new models with BigInt and manipuate olds manually.

I found the next solution. I changed the field to custom:

```
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'project.db.models.CustomBigAutoField'
```

And then overrided its deconstruction:

```py
from django.db import models

class CustomBigAutoField(models.BigAutoField):
    """Int8 field that is applied only for new models."""

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        if getattr(self, 'model', None):
            path = 'django.db.models.AutoField'
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

As I discovered, fields of new models don't have a back reference to their models, so `path` wouldn't be overridden for them.
We override `path` because Django checks whether a model is changed by a key, that includes the path to this field. So we deceive Django and it thinks that existing model didn't changed.

I might not see the whole picture, but I tested it with different existing and new models and it worked for me. If someone tells me why this solution is bad, I'd be grateful.