# I could simply delete the migration 0001_initial.py but it is not recommended to delete , so how could I fix this one without deletion of migration

Tags: django, django-cms

```
raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration home.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('cms', '0024_auto_20210516_0955')
```

Comment: You can `Comment `out the models and then `migrate` it and then apply with your changes again ... this way new files will be generated but first will ramain in` db` as well

Comment: It's your initial migration itself, meaning likely you have no migrations applied? Looks like the problem is you uninstalled some dependency? Just delete the migrations (don't delete the directory / folder and `__init__.py`) without issues and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat actually I tried it already and works but why can't the 0001_initial.py couldn't migrate?

Comment: Because that migration had a dependency to a 3rd party package that you uninstalled (`cms`) if you didn't uninstall (doesn't matter if you don't use it, you would need it in `INSTALLED_APPS`, etc. just to make your migrations sensible) that then that migration would have been fine. If you don't want to delete then you would need to manually edit your migration files.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat cms is still installed in top of django .I am using django-cms where cms is installed in Installed_apps . It just don't create the migrations in that 0024_auto_20210516_0955 .

Comment: @Knight Wait but Django cms _does not_ have a migration `0024` (It only has till `0022`), do you use Django 3.2? Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67006488/migrating-models-of-dependencies-when-changing-default-auto-field